# Datatables.js issues and questions

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a action in my controller that returns a list of activities and this was rendering to my datatable without issue, however, I did not see the number of records displayed at the bottom of the table rendering properly.  I did some digging and it looks like there are some additional properties required to get this to work.  I added those properties in my controller and ajax call and now I see 'Showing 1 of 3 of 3 entries' but no data in my datatable.

So here is my controller action when the datatable displays results but 'Showing 0 of 0 ...' is displayed.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllActivities(int UserId)
{
    return Json(repository.GetAllActivities(UserId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table id="master" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="rpt_col_bg_head" style="width: 3%;"></th>
                <th class="rpt_col_bg_head" style="width: 20%;">Result</th>
                <th class="rpt_col_bg_detail" style="width: 20%;">Work Activity</th>
                <th class="rpt_col_bg_detail" style="width: 180px;">Effort(%)</th>
                <th class="rpt_col_bg_detail" style="width: 7%;">Status</th>
                <th class="rpt_col_bg_detail" style="width: 30%;">Were there any innovations</th>
                <th class="rpt_col_bg_detail text-center" style="width: 7%;">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var table = $('#master').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columnDefs" : [{
        "targets" : [0],
        "visible" : true,
        "searchable" : false
        }],
    "ajax" : {
        "type" : "POST",
        "url"  : "@Url.Action("GetAllActivities", "Activities")",
        "data"     : { "UserId" : employeeId },
        "dataSrc"  : ""
       },
       "columns": [
         { 
           "className" : "details-control", "orderable" : false, "data": "ActivityHistoryId" },
           { "data" : "ParentName" },
           { "data" : "ActivityName" },
           { "data" : "Effort" },
           { "data" : "Status" },
           { "data" : "Innovation" },
           { "defaultContent" : '<td><div><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="edit work activity" name="editWork"></button></div></td>' }]
});
```

[image]

According to the documentation below some additional properties are required to get the footer to work.
https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

I modified my controller action and html accordingly.....

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllActivities(int UserId)
{
    int count = 0;
    var data = repository.GetAllActivities(UserId);

    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        count++;
    }

    return Json(new { draw = 1, recordsTotal = count, recordsFiltered = count, data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

HTML

```
var table = $('#master').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columnDefs" : [{
      "targets" : [0],
      "visible" : true,
      "searchable" : false
     }],
     "ajax" : {
       "type" : "POST",
       "url" : "@Url.Action("GetAllActivities", "Activities")",
             "data" : { "UserId" : employeeId },
             "dataFilter" : function(data) {
               var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               json.recordsTotal = json.recordsTotal;
               json.recordsFiltered = json.recordsFiltered;
               json.data = json.data;
               return JSON.stringify(json);
            },
            "dataSrc"  : ""
          },
          "columns": [
            { "className" : "details-control", "orderable" : false, "data": "ActivityHistoryId" },
            { "data" : "ParentName" },
            { "data" : "ActivityName" },
            { "data" : "Effort" },
            { "data" : "Status" },
            { "data" : "Innovation" },
            { "defaultContent" : '<td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="edit work activity" name="editWork"></button></div></td>'     }]
});
```

Here is the JSON returned from my controller, which is valid.

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[{"ActivityHistoryId":1,"UserId":91,"WorkFlowId":4,"ActivityName":"Test Activity 1","ActivityDescription":"Description of Test Activity 1","Status":"\u003cspan class=\u0027badge badge-blue\u0027\u003eNot Started\u003c/span\u003e","Effort":10,"Innovation":false,"ParentId":2,"ParentName":"Test Result 1"},{"ActivityHistoryId":2,"UserId":91,"WorkFlowId":4,"ActivityName":"Test Activity 2","ActivityDescription":"Description of Test Activity 2","Status":"\u003cspan class=\u0027badge badge-blue\u0027\u003eNot Started\u003c/span\u003e","Effort":16,"Innovation":false,"ParentId":2,"ParentName":"Test Result 1"},{"ActivityHistoryId":3,"UserId":91,"WorkFlowId":4,"ActivityName":"Test Activity 3","ActivityDescription":"Description of Test Activity 3","Status":"\u003cspan class=\u0027badge badge-lightBlue\u0027\u003eIn Progress\u003c/span\u003e","Effort":25,"Innovation":false,"ParentId":5,"ParentName":"Test Result 2"}]}
```

And the datatable...

[image]

Any idea how to get BOTH the datatable to render data AND show the number of entries in the table?  I find the documentation does not work for every scenario I try.

I used the following to see the data returned...

```
table.on('xhr', function () {
    var json = table.ajax.json();
    console.log(table.ajax.json());
});
```

[image]

Comment: does it give any error in developer tool console?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No error.  JSON data is returned and when I use consolg.log I can see the returned array in the data property.

Comment: Could you remove the line `"dataSrc": ""` and try again please?

Comment: @annoyingmouse BINGO!  That appears to have solved the issue.  I had dataSrc in the payload because I was not able to get the grid to populate BUT that was BEFORE I tried to add the footer.  Thanks!  Create this as an answer and I will credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `dataSrc` things should start working:

```
var table = $('#master').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [0],
    "visible": true,
    "searchable": false
  }],
  "ajax": {
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "@Url.Action("
    GetAllActivities ", "
    Activities ")",
    "data": {
      "UserId": employeeId
    },
    "dataFilter": function(data) {
      var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      json.recordsTotal = json.recordsTotal;
      json.recordsFiltered = json.recordsFiltered;
      json.data = json.data;
      return JSON.stringify(json);
    }
  },
  "columns": [{
    "className": "details-control",
    "orderable": false,
    "data": "ActivityHistoryId"
  }, {
    "data": "ParentName"
  }, {
    "data": "ActivityName"
  }, {
    "data": "Effort"
  }, {
    "data": "Status"
  }, {
    "data": "Innovation"
  }, {
    "defaultContent": '<td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="edit work activity" name="editWork"></button></div></td>'
  }]
});
```

Glad that helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see problem with the data or server side code - it is the way you are assigning data.

I just assigned data without AJAX and it works see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jituce/1naw041z/6/

```
var table = $('#master').DataTable( {
"processing": true,
"data":[{"ActivityHistoryId":1,"UserId":91,"WorkFlowId":4,"ActivityName":"Test Activity 1","ActivityDescription":"Description of Test Activity 1","Status":"\u003cspan class=\u0027badge badge-blue\u0027\u003eNot Started\u003c/span\u003e","Effort":10,"Innovation":false,"ParentId":2,"ParentName":"Test Result 1"},{"ActivityHistoryId":2,"UserId":91,"WorkFlowId":4,"ActivityName":"Test Activity 2","ActivityDescription":"Description of Test Activity 2","Status":"\u003cspan class=\u0027badge badge-blue\u0027\u003eNot Started\u003c/span\u003e","Effort":16,"Innovation":false,"ParentId":2,"ParentName":"Test Result 1"},{"ActivityHistoryId":3,"UserId":91,"WorkFlowId":4,"ActivityName":"Test Activity 3","ActivityDescription":"Description of Test Activity 3","Status":"\u003cspan class=\u0027badge badge-lightBlue\u0027\u003eIn Progress\u003c/span\u003e","Effort":25,"Innovation":false,"ParentId":5,"ParentName":"Test Result 2"}], 
"serverSide": false,
"columnDefs" : [{
    "targets" : [0],
    "visible" : true,
    "searchable" : false
    }],

   "columns": [
     { 
       "className" : "details-control", "orderable" : false, "data": "ActivityHistoryId" },
       { "data" : "ParentName" },
       { "data" : "ActivityName" },
       { "data" : "Effort" },
       { "data" : "Status" },
       { "data" : "Innovation" },
       { "defaultContent" : '<td><div><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="edit work activity" name="editWork"></button></div></td>' }]});
```

I would say remove JSON.stringy or dataFilter from the AJAX  and it should work fine.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Jitendra, thanks for the feedback.  I mentioned above that I can get the data to show up OR I can get the footer to work but I was not able to get BOTH working at the same time.  You have reproduced what I already had working and the jsfiddle does not work either.  Do you have any suggestions to get BOTH the footer and the grid to work?  The link I provided explains those additional items that I added to the json returned from the service.